# HIbernate 5: generator class="sequence" not working

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-5.x

I have following mapping:

```
    <id name="id" type="java.lang.Long" column="id">
        <generator class="sequence">
            <param name="sequence">tracksdata_seq</param>
        </generator>
    </id>
```

Everything went fine when I worked with it in Hibernate 4.2. Now I am migrating to Hibernate 5 and facing following issue:

```
2015-10-06 19:49:50 DEBUG SQL:92 - select nextval ('hibernate_sequence')
2015-10-06 19:49:50 DEBUG SqlExceptionHelper:122 - could not extract ResultSet [n/a]
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "hibernate_sequence" does not exist
```

How to resolve this issue?

P.S. Hibernate 5.0.2.Final.

Comment: It is looking for sequence hibernate_sequence, did you mention that in the mapping above? You have tracksdata_seq, not sure if that is refering to hyberante_sequence

Comment: This should not be referring to hibernate_sequence - it must use tracksdata_seq, like it was in hibernate 4.2.

Comment: @maksim2020 I had the same issue migrating from 4.3.8 to 5.0.6Final. This only happens if you use XML mappings. I switched to JPA annotations and it worked fine.

Comment: Notice that the param name is no longer "sequence", rather as of version 5 it is "sequence_name". See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42191210/why-does-hibernate-5-sequence-generator-use-the-default-hibernate-seq-instead-of

Answer (score 16):

You have two options:

1. You set the `hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings` configuration property to false and switch back to the old identifier generators
2. You change the mapping as follows, from this:

   ```xml
   <generator class="sequence">
       <param name="sequence">MY_SEQUENCE</param>
   </generator>
   ```

   to:

   ```xml
   <generator class="org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator">
       <param name="optimizer">none</param>
       <param name="increment_size">1</param>
       <param name="sequence_name">MY_SEQUENCE</param>
   </generator>
   ```

Comment: Spring boot format: spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings.  But I also needed spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema for hibernate to use the correct schema name

Answer (score 4):

Use `"sequence_name"` instead of `"sequence"` in `<param name="sequence">`.

That worked for me.

Comment: The class="sequence" generator was deprecated, so probably worthwhile changing it as specified in other answers, but this change is easier in the meantime, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered this problem when migrating from Hibernate 4.3.10 to Hibernate 5.0.4. Like maksim2020, I replaced instances of `<generator class="sequence">` with `<generator class="identity">`. However, to preserve the id sequence for the affected tables I also had to write a sql migration script which set the default value for the column to be the next value of the existing sequence. In PostgreSQL this is done as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE ONLY affected_table ALTER COLUMN affected_id SET DEFAULT nextval('original_sequence'::regclass);
```