# Why does Hibernate 5 sequence generator use the default hibernate.seq instead of my sequence?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-5.x

Aftre migrate my application from hibernate 4 to hibernate 5 .my sequence dose not work and hibernate use our default sequence instead of my sequence .my mapping config in hbm like this my database is oracle .

```
<id name="id"  column="Id" type="java.lang.Long">
    <generator class="sequence" >
            <param name="sequence">SEQ_APP_Login_Log</param>   
    </generator>
</id>
```

after google some people say change class to    org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator 
but dose not work again.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's simple. The `sequence` attribute has changed to `sequence_name`:

```
<id name="id" column="Id" type="java.lang.Long">
    <generator class="sequence" >
            <param name="sequence_name">SEQ_APP_Login_Log</param>   
    </generator>
</id>
```

Comment: how can i using sequence_name in both hibernate 4 and 5 ,I have framework that use in more than 10 Enterprise App . i want to migrate to hibernate 5 and change this hbm but i want my framework work in both version

Answer (score 0):

class "sequence" is shortcut for "org.hibernate.id.SequenceGenerator" which is deprecated.
use the following for hibernate5+:

```
<generator class="org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator">
    <param name="optimizer">none</param>
    <param name="increment_size">1</param>
    <param name="sequence_name">MY_SEQUENCE</param>
</generator>
```