# ORA-02289: sequence does not exist after upgrading from hibernate 3.2 to 5.2.12

Tags: java, hibernate, migration, hibernate-mapping, sessionfactory

Below is the code which was working in hibernate 3.2

```
public class Hibernate3Session {    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
        sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory();
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        org.hibernate.Transaction tr = session.beginTransaction();

        Employee emp = new Employee();
        emp.setName("Employee1");
        emp.setContactNumber("111111");
        emp.setAddress("XYZ location");

        session.save(emp);
        tr.commit();
        session.close();        

        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Below are the Employee Table

```
CREATE TABLE Employee
(
  ID                     NUMBER(10)             NOT NULL,
  NAME                   VARCHAR2(50 CHAR)      NOT NULL,
  CONTACT_NUMBER         VARCHAR2(50 CHAR),
  ADDRESS                VARCHAR2(50 CHAR),
  PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);



and the sequences used for the same
CREATE SEQUENCE SEQ_EMPLOYEE_ID  
                                MINVALUE 1 
                                NOMAXVALUE 
                                INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 NOCACHE  NOCYCLE ;
```

Below is the hibernate.cfg.xml file

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:dbname</property>
        <property name="connection.username">SYSTEM</property>
        <property name="connection.password">systempassword</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect</property>                
        <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit">true</property>        
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <mapping resource="Employee.hbm.xml" />

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Below are the corresponding Employee.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="Employee" table="EMPLOYEE" >
        <id name="id" type="long" >
            <column name="ID" />
            <generator class="sequence">
                <param name="sequence">SEQ_EMPLOYEE_ID</param>
            </generator>
        </id>
        <property name="name" type="string">
            <column name="NAME" length="50" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="contactNumber" type="string">
            <column name="CONTACT_NUMBER" length="50" />
        </property>
        <property name="address" type="string">
            <column name="ADDRESS" length="50" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Below are the corresponding POJO classes for the same

```
public class Employee {

    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String contactNumber;
    private String address;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getContactNumber() {
        return contactNumber;
    }
    public void setContactNumber(String contactNumber) {
        this.contactNumber = contactNumber;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }
    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((address == null) ? 0 : address.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((contactNumber == null) ? 0 : contactNumber.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
        return result;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Employee other = (Employee) obj;
        if (address == null) {
            if (other.address != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!address.equals(other.address))
            return false;
        if (contactNumber == null) {
            if (other.contactNumber != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!contactNumber.equals(other.contactNumber))
            return false;
        if (id == null) {
            if (other.id != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!id.equals(other.id))
            return false;
        if (name == null) {
            if (other.name != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!name.equals(other.name))
            return false;
        return true;
    }   
}
```

The code using for hibernate 5.2 final version is as below

```
public class Hibernate5vSession {   
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = null;
        StandardServiceRegistryBuilder registryBuilder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
        MetadataSources sources = new MetadataSources(registryBuilder.build());
        //sources.addResource("EmployeeRegistration.hbm.xml");
        Metadata metaData = sources.getMetadataBuilder().build();       
        sessionFactory = metaData.getSessionFactoryBuilder().build();

        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        org.hibernate.Transaction tr = session.beginTransaction();

        Employee emp = new Employee();
        emp.setName("Employee1");
        emp.setContactNumber("111111");
        emp.setAddress("XYZ location");

        session.save(emp);
        tr.commit();
        session.close();        

        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Also changed the Dialect below:

```
<property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>
```

Getting below error

Hibernate: select hibernate_sequence.nextval from dual
Mar 06, 2018 7:56:02 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 2289, SQLState: 42000
Mar 06, 2018 7:56:02 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: ORA-02289: sequence does not exist

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:106)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:69)
    at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStructure$1.getNextValue(SequenceStructure.java:95)
    at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.NoopOptimizer.generate(NoopOptimizer.java:40)
    at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator.generate(SequenceStyleGenerator.java:452)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:105)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:177)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:32)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:691)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:683)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:678)
    at HibernateSessionFactory.main(HibernateSessionFactory.java:62)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-02289: sequence does not exist

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:125)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:305)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:272)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.receive(T4C8Oall.java:626)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:185)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.execute_for_describe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:503)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.execute_maybe_describe(OracleStatement.java:951)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.execute_maybe_describe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:535)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1046)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:2905)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:2946)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:60)
    ... 13 more
```

**Note:** Have verified the Privileges at Oracle. The table is present in admin user System schema and the same is used for credentials.

I have obtained the SessionFactory as mentioned [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html).

In console it looks from hibernate sequence rather than Oracle

```
Hibernate: select hibernate_sequence.nextval from dual
Mar 06, 2018 10:26:47 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 2289, SQLState: 42000
```

why this is not working when i upgrade the hibernate version to 5.2.12

Any help in this?.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32978645/hibernate-5-generator-class-sequence-not-working

Comment: @Ivan, Thanks a lot for the help. I used <param name="sequence_name"> and worked for me.